# Stealth Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, publish, hidden

Is there a way to control whether or not the Facebook like button publishes the link like to the users Facebook wall?  I want to allow the user to subscribe to updates for one some of my pages, without telling the world that they are interested in that content.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is up to the user to decide if they want to publish those stories or not.